# Difficulty Loading Images in UV Editor

Tags: uv, image

I cannot load an image in the UV/Image editor. I can find the image in the browser, and when I click "open image" the file name displays as if it has loaded, but I cannot see anything. I've tried lots of different image files and also both .png and .jpg files.
I'm using Blender 2.74.
Thanks!
[image]

Comment: You don't see the image on the model or in the UV editor window?

Comment: If you are in UV/Image editor use ALT + O , then find your image and open it. I hope this works.

Comment: Thank you Ken and gladys for your replies! I've added a screenshot to my question. No matter what image I try to load in this .blend file, I see nothing in the UV editor. When I open some of my other .blend files, I can see loaded images just fine, so I feel like I am missing something.

Comment: You have more than one material assigned to that object. Have you assigned the "artwork_eatsheep" material to the object vertices in Edit mode? Has the object been UV unwrapped yet? What does it look like in Material mode or in Render mode?

Comment: Can you add a screenshot with the N panel open?

Comment: I replaced the screenshot to one with the N panel open. I can see now the error message "Can't Load Image" below the image title, which I hadn't seen before. Gladys - I had tried loading the artwork_eatsheep.jpg.001 file first, and had the same problem. But when I open a new .blend file, I can load any image into the UV editor without trouble. Todd, I went back through and tried removing all the materials from the objects in edit and object mode. Still can't seem to load the image.  I appreciate you all helping me troubleshoot this.

Comment: What you are experiencing seems abnormal to me... I suggest uninstalling blender, deleting all preferences files and reinstalling.

Comment: Could you post a similar screenshot of the problem while using a different image texture of small size located on the desktop?

Answer (score 0):

If you click on the image in the UV editor (1 in the picture below), the name of the image pops up and if i'm correct the name is artwork_eatsheep.jpg.001.
Then open the properties tab (N). Under image you see the source (2), here you must locate the image on your computer and load it. Then it should work.[image]

Comment: Thank you for uploading the image. I get an error message in the area of red box #2 in your screenshot. It says "can't load image."

Comment: If you are in the N panel and you go to the source, then you must click on the map icon and search for your texture on your computer. And then it should work. If it still doesn't work could you send me the blendfile?

Comment: and the jpg files you want to load in the blendfile.

Comment: @ChristopherReinhart Is there any output in the console/terminal?